# Como cambiar los values de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

estoy haciendo un proyecto en react y estoy consumiendo una api(superhéroes) el cual tiene los atributos de cada héroe, es decir, fuerza:"80", velocidad:"30", defensa:"50" etc.
Lo que hago con estos valores es sumarlos y algunos de estos atributos no tienen la suficiente información, y por defecto vienen con el value de "null". Ej: fuerza:"null", velocidad: "null".
Hay alguna forma de que si el value que viene es "null", poder cambiarlo por 0 por ejemplo?. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Si, si hay forma... pero... que has intentado? debes mostrar al menos parte del código para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Prueba con un ternario, un ejemplo podría ser  ` heroe.strength === null ? 0 : heroe.strength`